# Why do website host handles dns to resolve services(mail.domain.com ftp etc) instead of the domain registry?

Tags: dns-zone, dns-hosting

I have bought a new hosting service, and needed to change the name servers pointing to the new host for my website. When I did , all other subdomains especially ftp, mail subdomain and mx record broke.

I was told I have set up the dns resolution again in my host cpanel to fix this. So I wonder why cant it be set up in the domain registry? Why not point the website to the host which have all my files, and the rest leave as it is?

My suspicion is, correct me if Im wrong. That in able to find the domain.com IP, it needs go through the domain "." root then "com" top level and finally my domain. Once it finds where its sitting, it resolve the rest of names like @, then mail subdomain , ftp etc.But since it doesnt have any record to where to find it , it just stops. The thing is why cant it just go back to the domain registry to find the other info?

Please do let me know If Im understanding this all wrong.

PS: Current situation is I have a website in a cloud server on rackspace, our website points to that site and mails, ftp etc points to other server. So if this works why do I have to change the dns records in my hosting too. Really confused.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply how DNS de-centralised nature works. There is no central registry for DNS zone information, because it would be a single point of failure.

And even if there was a central registry for backup lookups, then there would be the problem of keeping records in sync with the actual domain.

You need to make sure your DNS zone is correct for all your services in the new DNS provider. You don't need to point all services to the new provider's servers. You can point DNS entries anywhere you want to.

Comment: Yes thats actually what I just found out. I can just create an A record in the domain registry and point domain.com to an IP address. Instead of changing the nameserver altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer to this. If you have a separate web host, ftp server and mail server in different server and all set up.

To point your website to your host, only update the A record domain.com to your web host IP address never the name server. And your other A record like mail.domain.com to your specified mail server ip and ftp.domain.com to your ftp server.